# Macro for copying cells from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a macro that copies a specific range of cells from one workbook to a new workbook. The macro would copy cells `A1:HC5` from `"Workbook1"`, and paste into the same cells `(A1:HC5)` of `"Workbook2"`. 
Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: `any guidance!` - try the macro recorder as you do it manually :)

Comment: The `Range.Copy` method will be useful.  [Details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178833(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: @SeanCheshire I'm stealing that link. Forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Sub test()
   Dim wbk As Workbook

   strFirstFile = "C:\source.xls"
   strSecondFile = "C:\destination.xls"

      Range("A1:HC35").Copy

   Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strSecondFile)
   With wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
      Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
      False, Transpose:=False
   End With 
End Sub
```