# Copying cells from multiples sheets of one workbook to multiple sheets in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a macro that copies a specific range of cells from sheets one workbook to respective sheets of new workbook. The macro would copy cells A1:HC5 from "Sheet 1" of  "Workbook1", and paste into the same cells (A1:HC5) of "Sheet 1" of "Workbook2". Then Sheet 2 should follow and then sheet 3 and so on.

Both workbooks have same number of sheets with same sheet names e.g. Page 1, Page 2 and so on. Number of sheets in the workbooks exceeds 2000.

I tried code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976058/macro-for-copying-cells-from-one-workbook-to-another?answertab=votes#tab-top) but it copies from Sheet 1 of first workbook to sheet 1 of second workbook. Need code that copies data from all sheets.

Please note I do not intend to consolidate specific data from multiple sheets in to a single sheet or summary sheet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA: Copy cells from multiple sheets to a single sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588637/excel-vba-copy-cells-from-multiple-sheets-to-a-single-sheet)

Comment: Thanks, I did check that post,  but my requirement is different. I do not want to consolidate data from m ultiple sheets to a single one but rather export pre-selected cells from multiple sheets of one workbook to other respective sheets of second workbook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Macro for copying cells from one workbook to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976058/macro-for-copying-cells-from-one-workbook-to-another)

Comment: Isn't this very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976058/macro-for-copying-cells-from-one-workbook-to-another   it even references the same cell range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, let me know if you have any questions.

The code should be run from the old workbook, and the new workbook should already be created and the variable changed in the code.

```
Sub copyAllSheetsToWorkbook()

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim copyToWrkbk As String

    Set x = ActiveWorkbook
    'change this to the name of the workbook you're copying to
    copyToWrkbk = "book3.xlsm"

    Workbooks.Open x.Path & "\" & copyToWrkbk
    Set y = ActiveWorkbook

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count

        x.Activate
        Sheets(i).Select
        Range("A1:HC5").Copy
        y.Activate
        Sheets(i).Select
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    Next i

End Sub
```